# Go REST API not reachable using docker-compose

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I am trying to run a simple go Rest API created with Gin Gonic and MySQL and PHPMyAdmin with docker.

While the PHPMyAdmin is running fine, when I try to access my go API I get the following error message: `localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

If I run my `main.go` file without docker, everything is working as expected

here is my `docker-compose` file

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: full_app
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    expose:
      - 8080
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=fullstack-mysql
      - DB_NAME=${DB_NAME}
      - DB_USER=${DB_USER}
      - DB_PASSWORD=${DB_PORT}
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app/
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-mysql
    networks:
      - fullstack

  fullstack-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: full_db_mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=${DB_HOST}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DB_USER}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=${DB_ROOT_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DB_NAME}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - database_mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - fullstack

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: phpmyadmin_container
    depends_on:
      - fullstack-mysql
    environment:
      - PMA_HOST=fullstack-mysql
      - PMA_USER=${DB_USER}
      - PMA_PORT=${DB_PORT}
      - PMA_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 9090:80
    restart: always
    networks:
      - fullstack

volumes:
  api:
  database_mysql:

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  fullstack:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```yaml
# Start from golang base image
FROM golang:alpine as builder

# ENV GO111MODULE=on

# Install git.
# Git is required for fetching the dependencies.
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git

# Set the current working directory inside the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy go mod and sum files
COPY go.mod go.sum ./

# Download all dependencies. Dependencies will be cached if the go.mod and the go.sum files are not changed
RUN go mod download

# Copy the source from the current directory to the working Directory inside the container
COPY . .

# Build the Go app
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o main .

# Start a new stage from scratch
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

WORKDIR /root/

# Copy the Pre-built binary file from the previous stage. Observe we also copied the .env file
COPY --from=builder /app/main .
COPY --from=builder /app/.env .

# Expose port 8080 to the outside world
EXPOSE 8080

#Command to run the executable
CMD ["./main"]
```

And here is my go `main.go` file (for now):

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/", func(context *gin.Context) {
        context.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"data": "Hello World !"})
    })

    router.Run("localhost:8080")
}
```

If I access `http://localhost:9090` PhpMyAdmin is loading (exactly what I am expecting)
If I access `http://localhost:8080` I get this error message: `localhost didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

I run `docker-compose up --build` for this.
I am obviously doing something wrong, but I am not sure what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the issue lies in your Go code and the way I am specifying the host for my API to listen on. In my `main.go` file, I am currently setting the host as "localhost:8080", but when running my application inside a Docker container, I should listen on "0.0.0.0:8080" instead. This allows the container to bind to all network interfaces.

To fix the issue, I had to modify the `router.Run` line in my `main.go` file as follows:

```golang
router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")
```

After making this change, I rebuilt my Docker image and run my containers again using docker-compose up --build. This should allow my Go REST API to be accessible on `http://localhost:8080` outside of the Docker container.

Note: The `localhost` inside the container refers to the container itself, not the host machine. By using "0.0.0.0", I am instructing the container to bind to all available network interfaces, allowing me to access the API from my host machine.